# Which APIs does Google provide to get the data of the User Activity Report and Cohort Report in the Report under the admob control panel

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-api, admob

I now use Google's admob service and firebase service, through the api provided by admob:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.report,
Write programs that can pull advertising and revenue data: Campaigns Report - Mediation and Ad Campaign Report - AdMob Network.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAQBS.png)
But the above api only provides accounts.mediationReport and accounts.networkReport, these two methods.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eMd5.png)

Is there any way I can programmatically pull data from User Activity Report and cohort report?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlgJ7.png)

I asked the business staff of Google Admob before, and said that the data of these two reports is provided by firebase, but I checked all the APIs of firebase, I didn’t see the relevant interface and method,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYvec.png)
who can help me, thank you!